# Spring @Transactional annotation usage with multiple transaction managers

Tags: java, spring, transactions

Good Day everyone!

As in my title my project has multiple(2) transaction managers:

- 1 custom (`name = customTransactionManager`), currently annotated with `@Primary`
- 1 autogenerated from Spring JPA (`name = jpaTransactionManager`), new
  We are currently modifying all our entities to JPA, and when I'm rewriting dao layer, I will need new `@Transactional` annotation on top of another. Example is below

```
@Transactional("jpaTransactionManager")
override fun deleteByIds(ids: List<Int>): Int {

        if (ids.isEmpty()) {
            return 0
        }
        platformsDao.deleteByIdIn(ids)

        log.info { "Was deleted '${ids.size}' platforms" }

        return ids.size
    }
```

```
@Repository
interface PlatformsDao : CrudRepository<PlatformEntity, Int> {

    @Transactional <----
    fun deleteByIdIn(ids: List<Int>)

    fun getAllByDisplayNameStartingWith(regex: String): MutableList<PlatformEntity>
}
```

If I don't write name will it be automaticaly `jpaTransactionManager`?

Comment: I know that I can just add name, but what if name just passed from 1st annotation, I know for a fact that CrudRepository.save has @Transactional and it seems to not break during runtime

Comment: Why did you make a customTransactionManager if you still want to use the default one anyway?

Comment: @ValerijDobler we were transitioning from jdbc to jpa. JpaRepository has Transactional annotation on save and delete by default. What I was worried about was will it work if I had 2 transactionManagers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you generate 2 different transactionManagers with `JpaTransactionManager` as default, it will work!